# Maven pom to have working cucumber

Tags: eclipse, maven, cucumber

I keep on getting a gherkin "cannot find formatter" error when i run my very very basic cucumber test.

Any ideas? I really really wish people just made IT *easy*, it's always such a pain to set things up /rant

Below is my maven pom, but first the error I get:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/formatter/Formatter

Anyway, I'll give 500 bounty to anyone who comes up with this solution, this is ludicrous.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>cucumber-a</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-a</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>cucumber</name>
<description>Basic Playground for Cucumber</description>
<dependencies>

<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
 <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
  <plugins>
     <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.1</version>
     <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
     </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the cucumber docs are p-retty bad.

Everyone there should feel sad.

But! Someone who is amazing put up this skellington document:
[this is amazing](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton)

It is all the stuff you need for cucumber fun (hahhaha!) and it comes supporting maven, ant, whatever.

This is so useful it cannot be overlooked - I think my problem was a corrupt maven download (my firewall kicked in halfway ?idk) but using this just made everything lovely.

Thanks person who won't read this because idk how to tag it!

Comment: Well, I read it and I am the last person to commit to the skeleton project. And I agree, the docs can be improved.